# Azure Policy for Inheriting Tags from Resource Group is giving error

Tags: azure-policy

I am trying to create a custom Azure Policy for which all the resources will inherit tags from its parent resource group.

This is my policy definition:

```json
{
    "properties": {
      "displayName": "Inherit tags from Resource Group",
      "policyType": "Custom",
      "mode": "All",
      "description": "Adds the specified tag with its value from the parent resource group.",
      "metadata": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "category": "General"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "listOfTagNames": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Required Tags",
            "description": "The list of required tags"
          }
        }
      },
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[0], ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[0]]]",
                "notEquals": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[1], ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[1]]]",
                "notEquals": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[2], ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[2]]]",
                "notEquals": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[3], ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[3]]]",
                "notEquals": ""
            },
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[4], ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[4]]]",
                "notEquals": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "modify",
            "details": {
                "roleDefinitionIds": [
                "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
            ],
            "operations": [
                {
                    "operation": "add",
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[0], ']')]",
                    "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[0]]]"
                },
                {
                    "operation": "add",
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[1], ']')]",
                    "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[1]]]"
                },
                {
                    "operation": "add",
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[2], ']')]",
                    "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[2]]]"
                },
                {
                    "operation": "add",
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[3], ']')]",
                    "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[3]]]"
                },
                {
                    "operation": "add",
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('listOfTagNames')[4], ']')]",
                    "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('listOfTagNames')[4]]]"
                }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
But this is giving me following error:
"message":"The policy definition 'InheritTagsFromRGPolicy' rule is invalid. 
The policy effect details contains operations on duplicate fields in 'add' or 'addOrReplace' operations: 'tags[]'."
```

Answer (score 0):

> The policy effect details contains operations on duplicate fields in 'add' or 'addOrReplace' operations: 'tags[]'."

The error message states that there are duplicate fields in the `add` or `addOrReplace` operations for the `tags` field. If you specify duplicate tags in the parameter field while assigning the policy, you will receive the same error.

I encountered the same error when I provided duplicated values during the assignment process.

[image]

To resolve the issue, you need to ensure that you're not specifying duplicate tags in the `add` operations during the assignment process.

If I specify unique tag values as below.

[image]

Once I specify the unique tag values in parameters, I am able to assign the policy successfully as below.

[image]